# what does "spending upwards of" mean here

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrases

If someone asks -

> Do you think spending an upwards of 100 bucks would make sense?

I think that means spending 100 more than something. But since they've not specified compared to what. Please, help me with what that means.

Comment: [*Upwards of*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/upwards%20of): "more than : in excess of." The only thing that doesn't make sense in the sentence is the use of **an**.

Comment: "Do you think spending upwards of (more than) 100 bucks"  would make sense? would make sense

Comment: **A sum** upwards of $100 would make sense.

Comment: We also (at least in the UK) sometimes say e.g. "North of £100" to mean the same thing, North being at the top of a map conventionally.

Answer (score 2):

"Upwards of" (or less commonly "upward of") [means "more than" or "in excess of."](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/upwards%20of)

Accordingly, spending "upwards of $100" does **not** mean spending "$100 more than" some unspecified amount, as you seem to suggest in your question. Rather, it simply means spending some amount that is **more than $100**.

In practice, most native speakers would assume that "upwards of $100" referred to an amount not vastly higher than $100. That is, I might say something cost "upward of $100" if it cost $110 or $125. I wouldn't be likely to say that if it cost $200. Likewise, I might say I had lived in New York for "upwards of ten years" if I had lived there for twelve or thirteen years, but probably not if I had lived there for eighteen years. (In that case, I'd be likelier to say "almost twenty years.")

Please note that "upwards" is not a noun and does not take an article. We say something cost "upwards of $100," not (as in your example) "an upwards of $100."

Finally, please note the distinction between "upwards of" and "up to." If I said I was willing to spend "up to $100" on something, it would mean I was willing to pay $100 or less, but not more.

Answer (score 0):

The dictionary definition is "more than." Under that definition, "Upwards of $100" would mean some amount close to, but greater than $100.

However, I've used and heard this phrase many times and it pretty much indicates that the actual amount is an indeterminate amount *less* than the stated amount and we are rounding up. So it would be a synonym for "up to." I just polled several native English speaking friends and they all agreed that is generally is a synonym for "up to."

> My gardner charges by the hour. Sometimes he only charges $80 to do my lawn, but it could be upwards of $100 if the grass is bad.

This means the amount he charges varies between $80 and $100. If he sometimes charges more than $100, you might hear

> upwards of $100 or more.

Which means it's normally less than $100 but very occasionally can exceed that amount.

A dictionary pedant would say that this is a redundant phrase, but it's very common. In fact, it's common enough that it's the normal way to hear things. A usage "mistake" kind of stops being a mistake at some point when it is common enough. Even if it is a mistake on some level, you are likely to hear it used this way if you interact with native speakers, so be prepared.

It also might be a localized definition, as I am located in the US and Mr. Harvey is in the UK.

Comment: "Upwards of" does not mean 'around' or "in the region of", it means "more than". $80 is not upwards of $100. Also, "Upwards of [something] **or more**" is redundant.

Comment: @michaelharvey No point in reiterating what I acknowledged in my answer.

Comment: You got the meaning of "upwards of" completely wrong.

Comment: Can't agree with your "poll".

Comment: The native English speakers you polled are simply wrong - or maybe the question you asked was misleading or misworded in some way. "Upwards of" certainly doesn't mean "up to."

Comment: @TypeIA I notice your profile says you are in Europe. So far all such comments have come from that side of the pond. I think there may be regional differences in how this term is used.

Comment: @farnsy I live in Germany but I grew up in the midwestern U.S. and am a native speaker from that region (lived there from birth for almost 40 years).